# Postgresql converting strings with parenthesis for negative and leading $ signs

Tags: postgresql, parentheses

I have values like these in data input and I have not been able to convert those with parenthesis to a negative numeric. I am using TO_NUMBER(a.Total_Paid,'L999999D99')

Example ($123.45)

It should be -123.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?  (Note that it does not work for me if I include the `L` in the format string)

```
to_number(translate('($123.45)', '()', '<>'), '999999d99PR')
```

Comment: Without the L it stills removes the $ sign

Comment: @Ken  Technically, it is ignoring the number sign when parsing the value into a numeric.